# Instance method 'drive' requires the types 'NotificationItem' and '[NotificationItem]' be equivalent

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have create a class called notification Item and parsing the data from model class RTVNotification

import Foundation
import RTVModel

public class NotificationItem: NSObject {

```
public var id: String
public var title: String
public var comment: String
public var publishStartDateString: String

init(id: String,
     title: String,
     comment: String,
     publishStartDateString: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.comment = comment
    self.publishStartDateString = publishStartDateString

    super.init()
}
```

}

extension NotificationItem {
    static func instantiate(with notification: RTVNotification) -> NotificationItem? {

```
    return NotificationItem(
        id: notification.id,
        title: notification.title,
        comment: notification.comment,
        publishStartDateString: notification.publishStartDateString)

}
```

}

ViewModel

public class SettingsViewModel: ViewModel {

```
var item = [NotificationItem]()

public var fetchedNotifications: Driver<NotificationItem> = .empty()

public var apiErrorEvents: Driver<RTVAPIError> = .empty()

public var notificationCount: Driver<Int> = .empty()

public func bindNotificationEvents(with trigger: Driver<Void>) {

    let webService: Driver<RTVInformationListWebService> = trigger
        .map { RTVInformationListParameters() }
        .webService()

    let result = webService.request()
    apiErrorEvents = Driver.merge(apiErrorEvents, result.error())
    notificationCount = result.success().map {$0.informationList.maxCount }
    fetchedNotifications =
         result.success()
        .map {$0.informationList.notifications}
```

----->      .map {NotificationItem.instantiate(with: $0)}

```
}
```

}

Getting an Error saying that Cannot convert value of type '[RTVNotification]' to expected argument type 'RTVNotification'
What can i do to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:
`fetchedNotifications: Driver<NotificationItem>` should be `fetchedNotifications: Driver<[NotificationItem]>` and the line `.map {NotificationItem.instantiate(with: $0)}` needs another map You are dealing with an `Observable<Array<RTVNotification>>`. You have a container type within a container type, so you need a map within a map:

```
.map { $0.map { NotificationItem.instantiate(with: $0) } }
```

When your types don't match, you need to change the types.

Other issues with your code...

- Drivers, Observables, Subjects and Relays should never be defined with `var`, they should always be `let`s. Objects that subscribe to your properties before the bind is called will connect to the `.empty()` observables and never get any values. This is *functional* reactive programming, after all.
- Your `NotificationItem` type should either be a `struct` or all it's properties should be `let's.

Be sure to read and understand @par's answer to this question. He wrote a really good explanation and it would be a shame to waste that knowledge transfer.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel T.  As someone who understands Swift well enough to mostly see the problem, I was aiming at providing some immediate assistance.  I was however definitely hoping someone who knows RxSwift would come along and write a much better "this is how the API works" -type answer.  +1 from me and let's hope OP returns to give you the green checkmark.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel T. I solved that problem but i am not able to convert the types getting this error:- ICannot convert value of type 'NotificationItem' to closure result type 'RTVNotification' Can u please help me out Im new to programming.

Comment: Create a new question with the kind of detail you gave this one and I'm sure you will get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `map()` function is to iterate over the elements of an input array and apply a transform function to each of those elements.  The transformed elements are added to a new output array that is returned by `map()`.  It's important to understand that the length of the output array is the same length as the input array.

For example:

```
let inputArray = ["red", "white", "blue"]
let outputArray = inputArray.map { $0.count } // outputArray is [3, 5, 4]
```

In your code, you are calling:

```
result.success().map { $0.informationList.notifications }
```

I don't know RxSwift at all, so I'm going to go into wild speculation here.

First, I don't know exactly what `result.success()` returns, but the fact you can call `map()` on it implies `result.success()` returns an array (which is weird, but ok we'll go with it).

Second, we know the array returned by `result.success()` contains elements that have an `informationList` property, and the `informationList` property has a property called `notifications`.  My guess is that `notifications`, being plural, means the `notifications` property type is an array, probably `[RTVNotification]`.

So this code:

`result.success().map { $0.informationList.notifications }`

Transforms the `success()` array into a new array.  Based on my assumption that `notifications` is of type `[RTVNotification]`, and further assuming the `success()` array contains only one element, I would expect the result of

`result.success().map { $0.informationList.notifications }`

To be an array of type `[[RTVNotification]]`, i.e. an array with one element, where that element is an array of `RTVNotification`s.

You then feed that `[[RTVNotification]]` array into another `map()` function:

`.map { NotificationItem.instantiate(with: $0) }`

Recall from the start of this answer that `map()` iterates over the elements of arrays.  Since the input array to this map is `[[RTVNotification]]`, its elements will be of type `[RTVNotification]`.  That's what the `$0` is in your call - `[RTVNotification]`.  But the `instantiate(with:)` function takes an `RTVNotification`, *not* an array of `RTVNotification`, thus you get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[RTVNotification]' to expected argument type 'RTVNotification'

So what can you do to fix it?

I would probably do something like this (you'll have to tailor it to your use case):

```
guard let successResponse = webService.request().success().first else {
    print("no success response received")
    return nil // basically report up an error here if not successful
}

// get the list of notifications, this will be type [RTVNotification]
let notifications = successResponse.informationList.notifications

// Now you can create an array of `[NotificationItem]` like you want:
let notificationItems = notifications.map { NotificationItem.instantiate(with: $0) }

// do something with notificationItems...
```

The caveat to the above is if you need to iterate over each element in the `success()` array, then you could do that like this:

```
let successResponses = webService.result().success()

// successNotifications is of type [[RTVNotification]]
let successNotifications = successResponses.map { $0.informationList.notifications }

// successItems will be of type [[NotificationItem]]
let successItems = successNotifications.map { notifications in
    notifications.map { NotificationItem.instantiate(with: $0) }
}
```

In other words, in this last case, you get back an array that contains arrays of `NotificationItem`.

Comment: Wow, for someone who doesn't know RxSwift, this is a really good answer. One caveat: The `map` (and `flatMap`) methods are just for arrays, they also exist in `Optional` and `Result` for e.g.. They can exist on any type that holds another type. In this case the `Observable` type includes a `map` method. The method allows you to manipulate the internal object without extracting it from its parent object.

Comment: Sorry the above should have said they _aren't_ just for arrays, not "are".